# Pull value from specified place in URL using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am brand new to regex and need some assistance in how to write an expression to pull the value after the third _ and fourth _ within my URL:

http://www.companyA.com?scid=sm_aw_ban_PQRSTUV_OP12561

I just want to find "PQRSTUV" (which will be different for every URL), and then using a separate regex find the value "OP12561" (which will also be different for every URL)

Comment: Why not just split on that character and get those values?

Comment: I probably should have shared that I am not a developer so I do not know how to do that. The software I'm using allows for regex, so I thought there might be a way to just look for the value that lies in a specific area of my URL.

Comment: Does the url always start with `http` and contain `www`?

Comment: Yes. It will also always include "?scid=" as well.

Comment: What language is this for? You should tag the language as well.

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance, this is working great now!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't absolutely have to use two separate regexes. The below should work for you.

```
var matches = url.match(/.*_.*_.*_(.*)_(.*)/);
```

access with `matches[1]` and `matches[2]`.

```js
var url='http://www.companyA.com?scid=sm_aw_ban_PQRSTUV_OP12561';

if (url.match(/.*_.*_.*_(.*)_(.*)/)) {
  
 $('#myDiv').append( url.match(/.*_.*_.*_(.*)_(.*)/)[1] + '<br><br>');
 $('#myDiv').append( url.match(/.*_.*_.*_(.*)_(.*)/)[2] );
    
} else {
 // Match attempt failed
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just did this in the javascript console, basically a capture group looking for everything between the second and third, and then another between the third and fourth:

```
y = new RegExp("_.*_(.*)_");
//-> /_.*_(.*)_/
x.match(y)
//-> ["_aw_ban_PQRSTUV_", "PQRSTUV"]
y = new RegExp("_.*_.*_(.*)");
//-> /_.*_.*_(.*)/
x.match(y)
//-> ["_aw_ban_PQRSTUV_OP12561", "OP12561"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the last part (OP12561):

```
[^_]+$
```

or "a nonempty string as long as possible, immediately preceding the end, that does not contain the character `_`"

For the second-to-last part (PQRSTUV):

```
(?<=_)[^_]+(?=_[^_]+$)
```

"the longest possible nonempty string that:

- does not contain the character `_`
- is immediately preceded by `_`
- is immediately followed by `_`, then a nonempty string not containing `_`, then end of string.
  "